# Why IO.puts prints to terminal in a module if is not called

Tags: elixir

I have a question, I have this module

```
defmodule Example do

  IO.puts "Creating a function"

  def sum(a, b) do
      a + b
  end

  IO.puts "End of the function”
end
```

when I compile this with elixirc example.ex I got this

```
Creating a function
End of the function
```

Why? I just compile the file and I am not calling this module from anywhere

Comment: I would say that you are mistaken and it is running it as well.  :-)

Comment: You're sure you did "elixirc"  not "elixir"?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, in fact, I did elixir and elixirc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining a module in Elixir *is* executing the code inside that module. In fact, even "def" itself is just a macro that gets the function contents and store them somewhere. Everything is an expression. That's why you can, for example, perform conditional definitions as:

```
defmodule Example do
  if true do
    def sum(a, b) do
      a + b
    end
  end
end
```

And that's why the code works the way you have seen.

PS: elixir and elixirc will show the same behaviour because the only difference between them is that one writes .beam files to disk, the other does not.

Comment: Thanks, I had the idea about that, but I was not sure. Now I am sure that everything is an expression and return a value.